# Special Characters to list in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the dataframe

```
data2 = {'col0' : ['USD<500','AUD>100','GBP>200'],
         'col1' : ['weights(kgs)','weights(lbs)','weights(gms)'],
         'col2' : ['USD$500','AUD$400','GBP$450'],
         'col3' : ['height[cm]','height[mm]','height[m]'],
         'col4' : ['length*10%','length*100%','length*1000%'],
         'col5' : ['exp^2','exp^3','exp^4'],
         'col6' : ['length.height','height.weight','length.weight'],
         'col7' : ['len?ht','ht?wt','len?wt'],
         'col8' : ['length+height','height+weight','length+weight']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data2)
```

It has lot of special characters, I need to extract all the special characters to a list, already I have a list of pre-defined characters to check

I am not after cleaning the characters, just i need to create a list of characters that are present in the dataframe

I tried

```
avaichars = []
for col in df2.columns:
    for ch in ["<",">","-","/","@","!","~","#","&","?","`"," ",",",":",";","(",")","[","]","*","^",".","?","+","%"]:
        if df2[col].str.contains(ch).sum() != 0: 
            print(col,ch,df2[col].str.contains(ch).sum())
            avaichars.append(ch)
```

I find no issues finding these characters

```
"<",">","-","/","@","!","~","#","&","?","`"," ",",",":",";"
```

But

```
"(",")","[","]","*","^",".","?","+","%"
```

these characters throwing error as : nothing to repeat
and '$' showing to be in all strings

May I know how to extract the characters

Expected outcome

```
avaichars = ["<",">","(",")","$","[","]","%","*","^",".","?","+"]
```

Comment: looks like `str.contains` also takes regex as a default. There is a parameter for the `str.contains` function called `regex` it's default is true. Try setting it to false.

Comment: As the comment says, it seems to be a regular expression, so you can get it by putting a backslash at the beginning of the string you can't get. I checked.

Comment: Yes, setting df2[col].str.contains(ch, regex=False) Worked